# Translation of basis for a vector space on the specified distance

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, transformation, 3d

In the Euclidean space $XYZ$ is a basis $X_1Y_1Z_1$ defined that is specified by the vectors $\overrightarrow {O_1X_1}$, $\overrightarrow {O_1Y_1}$ and $\overrightarrow {O_1Z_1}$. How to calculate vectors $\overrightarrow {O_2X_2}$, $\overrightarrow {O_2Y_2}$ and $\overrightarrow {O_2Z_2}$ of the new Basis $X_2Y_2Z_2$ if it is placed on the same line that is defined by the vector $\overrightarrow {O_1Y_1}$ and the distance between the Points $O_1$ and $O_2$ is $d$?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $O_1 Y_1$ has parameter equation: $\vec{X}=\vec{O_1}+ t \left( \vec{Y}-\vec{O_1}\right)$.
The distance between $O_1$ and $O_2$ is $d$, so $O_2$ the point on the line $O_1 Y_1$ with 
$$t=\frac{d}{\left| \vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1} \right|}$$
The absolute value signs stands for the norm of a vector. The translation vector $\vec{O_1 O_2}$ is equal to 
$$\frac{d}{\left| \vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1} \right|}(\vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1})$$
In conclusion:
$$\vec{X_2}=\vec{X_1}+\frac{d}{\left| \vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1} \right|}(\vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1})$$
$$\vec{Y_2}=\vec{Y_1}+\frac{d}{\left| \vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1} \right|}(\vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1})$$
$$\vec{Z_2}=\vec{Z_1}+\frac{d}{\left| \vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1} \right|}(\vec{Y_1}-\vec{O_1})$$

Comment: I need to translate $O_1$ to $O_2$, so the translation vector $\overrightarrow {O_1O_2}$. Can you please add the example for Translation of the $\overrightarrow {O_1X_1}$ in $\overrightarrow {O_2X_2}$. Thank you!

Comment: Please upgrade my answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: I've find some misunderstanding on my side. The vectors like $\overrightarrow {O_1X_1}$=$\overrightarrow {O_2X_2}$, because they are parallel with the same length. (My task: I wanted to create a transformation matrix from XYZ to $X_2Y_2Z_2$, but it is not a part of my question). So instead of to calculate a new basis (from the old specified by vectors like  $\overrightarrow {O_1X_1}$..., NOT the $\overrightarrow {OX_1}$...) you've calculated a new basis vectors like $\overrightarrow {OX_2}$ (not $\overrightarrow {O_2X_2}$). Is it so or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I have calculated the coordinates of $\vec{X_2}$ (which is an abbreviation of $\vec{OX_2}$) with respect to the origin $O$. Is that not what you're looking for?